# Redirect and pass form variables

Tags: c#, .net, http, stripe-payments

I am integrating with a 3rd party payment platform (Stripe). Their API is posting back a bunch of parameters in the HTTP post to an `aspx` page. What I need to do is read one of the FORM variables to know where the post should be forwarded to (i.e. it needs to be redirected to the user specific subdomain endpoint - https://user1.mayapp.com/newstripeaccount.aspx).

My questions is how in .NET can you forward the request and preserve all the http post parameters without meticulously parsing them out and using `HttpWebRequest` to construct a new HTTP post to the final endpoint. Is there a simpler way to redirect and just pass the `httpcontext`?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'd say just go ahead and read and re-write out the parameters. That way you can guarantee that the data you're sending on to your target is good (you can run some basic validations and filters), rather than whatever your client sent to you. This would also allow you to accept other parameters from your client that may be unrelated to your target, without passing them along. I'd expect it's not a ridiculous number of parameters, so it shouldn't be a ton of work.

Comment: It's an option, although I think if this proves to be problematic I would just move all the logic in the sub-domain to the proxy page and do all the processing there, then finally redirect to the sub-domain endpoint with a simple `response.redirect`.

Comment: @QF_Developer I'm not sure about your app setup, but I think moving your Stripe response parsing/processing logic to the proxy page is the way to go, especially if the sub-domain endpoint is a different app.